# upload a picture symfony

Tags: php, symfony, upload

i have a problem i think when i try to upload a file ,here is the message :

> The option "0" does not exist. Defined options are: "action", "allow_extra_fields", "attr", "auto_initialize", "block_name", "by_reference", "compound", "constraints", "csrf_field_name", "csrf_message", "csrf_protection", "csrf_token_id", "csrf_token_manager", "data", "data_class", "disabled", "empty_data", "error_bubbling", "error_mapping", "extra_fields_message", "inherit_data", "invalid_message", "invalid_message_parameters", "label", "label_attr", "label_format", "mapped", "method", "multiple", "post_max_size_message", "property_path", "required", "translation_domain", "trim", "upload_max_size_message", "validation_groups".

here my UserType :

```
     public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('lastName',TextType::class, array(
            'label'=> 'Nom',
            'attr'=> ['placeholder'=>'Votre Non']
        ))
        ->add('firstName',TextType::class, array(
            'label'=> 'Prénom',
            'attr'=> ['placeholder'=>'Votre Prénom']
        ))
        ->add('username',TextType::class, array(
            'label'=> 'Nom d\'utilisateur',
            'attr'=> ['placeholder'=>'Non d\'utilisateur ']
        ))
        ->add('email',EmailType::class, array(
            'label'=> 'Email',
            'attr'=> ['placeholder'=>'Votre Email']
        ))
        ->add('adresse',TextType::class, array(
            'label'=> 'Votre Adresse',
            'attr'=> ['placeholder'=>'Votre Adresse']
        ))
        ->add('ville',TextType::class, array(
            'label'=> 'Ville',
            'attr'=> ['placeholder'=>'Votre Ville']
        ))
        ->add('pays',TextType::class, array(
            'label'=> 'Pays',
            'attr'=> ['placeholder'=>'Votre Pays']
        ))
        ->add('codePostal',TextType::class, array(
            'label'=> 'Code Postal',
            'attr'=> ['placeholder'=>'Code Postal']
        ))
        ->add('telephone',TextType::class, array(
            'label'=> 'Télephone',
            'attr'=> ['placeholder'=>'Votre telephone']
        ))
        ->add('dateAnniversaire', BirthdayType::class, array(
            'label'=> 'Date D\'anniversaire',
            'placeholder' => array(
                'day'=>'Jour','month'=>'Mois' ,'year'=>'Année'
            )
        ))
        ->add('attachment',FileType::class,array(
            'label' => 'Photo de profil',
            'required' => false, (array(
                'data_class' => null
            ))
        ))
    ;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'UserBundle\Entity\User'
    ));
}


class User extends BaseUser
```

{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

```
/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(name="last_name" , type="string" , length=25, nullable=true)
 */
protected $lastName;

/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(name="first_name", type="string", length=25, nullable=true)
 */
protected $firstName;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="date_anniversaire", type="datetime", nullable = true)
 */
protected $dateAnniversaire;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="adresse", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
protected $adresse;

/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(name="ville", type="string", length=25, nullable=true)
 */
protected $ville;

/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(name="pays", type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
 */
protected $pays;

/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(name="code_postal", type="string",length=5, nullable=true)
 */
protected $codePostal;

/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(name="telephone", type="string", length=15, nullable=true)
 */
protected $telephone;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="UserBundle\Entity\User", cascade={"persist"})
 */
protected $users;


/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 * @Assert\File(
 *     mimeTypes={"image/jpeg","image/gif","image/png"},
 *     mimeTypesMessage = "Svp inserer une image valide (png,jpg,jpeg)")
 */
protected $attachment;


public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getLastName()
{
    return $this->lastName;
}

/**
 * @param string $lastName
 */
public function setLastName($lastName)
{
    $this->lastName = $lastName;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getFirstName()
{
    return $this->firstName;
}

/**
 * @param string $firstName
 */
public function setFirstName($firstName)
{
    $this->firstName = $firstName;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getDateAnniversaire()
{
    return $this->dateAnniversaire;
}

/**
 * @param string $dateAnniversaire
 */
public function setDateAnniversaire($dateAnniversaire)
{
    $this->dateAnniversaire = $dateAnniversaire;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getAdresse()
{
    return $this->adresse;
}

/**
 * @param string $adresse
 */
public function setAdresse($adresse)
{
    $this->adresse = $adresse;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getVille()
{
    return $this->ville;
}

/**
 * @param string $ville
 */
public function setVille($ville)
{
    $this->ville = $ville;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getPays()
{
    return $this->pays;
}

/**
 * @param string $pays
 */
public function setPays($pays)
{
    $this->pays = $pays;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getCodePostal()
{
    return $this->codePostal;
}

/**
 * @param string $codePostal
 */
public function setCodePostal($codePostal)
{
    $this->codePostal = $codePostal;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getTelephone()
{
    return $this->telephone;
}

/**
 * @param string $telephone
 */
public function setTelephone($telephone)
{
    $this->telephone = $telephone;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getUsers()
{
    return $this->users;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $users
 */
public function setUsers($users)
{
    $this->users = $users;
}


/**
 * Add user
 */
public function addUser($user)
{
    $this->users[] = $user;

}

/**
 * Remove user
 */
public function removeUser($user)
{
    $this->users->removeElement($user);
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getAttachment()
{
    return $this->attachment;
}

/**
 * @param string $attachment
 */
public function setAttachment($attachment)
{
    $this->attachment = $attachment;
}
```

before this error i had nothing , i was upload a picture :

somebody can helm me please?

controller edit :

```
    /**
 * @Route("/mon-espace/{id}/edit", name="edit")
 * @param Request $request
 * @param User $user
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function editAction(Request $request, User $user)
{
    $editForm = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);
    /*        dump($user);die();*/
    $editForm->handleRequest($request);

    if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid())
    {
        $file = $user->getAttachment();
            $fileName = md5(uniqid()).'.'.$file->guessExtension();
            $file->move($this->getParameter('attachment_directory'), $fileName);
            $user->setAttachment($fileName);

        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
        return $this->redirectToRoute('monEspace',array('user'=> $user->getId()));
    }

    return $this->render('@User/profil/edit.html.twig' , array(
        'user'=> $user,
        'editForm' => $editForm->createView()
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you forget  **->getForm()**  after last **->add**

```
   .
    .
    . ->add('attachment',FileType::class,array(
                'label' => 'Photo de profil',
                'required' => false, (array(
                    'data_class' => null
                ))
            ))
     ->getForm();
```

---

**Update**

You have not field username on entity ...So if you want to use of Many To Many relation tip you must do something like this.

```
         ->add('users',EntityType::class, array(
                  'class' => 'AppBundle:User',
    'label'=> 'Nom d\'utilisateur',
    'attr'=> ['placeholder'=>'Non d\'utilisateur ']
))
```

Comment: i thank you for the answer, i tried but it did not work, its the same error

Comment: Plz share your Entity and Form Type

Comment: oh yeah i forgot to say its about User entity on FosUser. so yeah i have already username on the database

Comment: Your program has error again?????. If it  plz update your questions and  share the  controller  cod too

Comment: yea i still have an error message its always the same one, i updated my question